# How can you add the input layer and last layer in mobilenetv2 bottleneck block when they're almost never the same size?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I am having a lot of trouble understanding this basic idea of the bottleneck block of the mobilenetv2 architecture. For stride = 1, where you add the input layer to the last layer (AKA a skip connection), these are virtually never the same size! How are you supposed to add to tensors that are almost never the same size.

I've tried to think about it in many ways and I can't see what is being done for stride=1.

Comment: Edit: I think I know solution via looking up random codes but I still argue this is vague and not mentioned in the paper. It seems an ADDITIONAL 1x1 convolution is needed on the input to match the output size. So its NOT final_layer = output_layer + input_layer. Its final_layer = output_layer + conv(output_size, (1,1))(input_layer)

Answer (score 0):

you can add the layer using model.add

```
import tensorflow as tf

base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(96,96,3),
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=( )))
```

Thank You.